# Echoing multiple lines in java through a single line of echo

Tags: java, shell

I have a Java code like this:

```
      "echo 'hello1' > abc.sh\n" +
      "echo 'hello2' >> abc.sh\n" +
      "echo 'hello3' >> abc.sh\n";
```

The first line opens the `abc.sh` shell file, and the next two lines appends the content (hello2 and hello3). Is there anyway I can do it in a single `echo` command itself instead of using multiple lines?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, there is a way

Comment: @Maurice Perry, can you please advise me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Echo accepts line feed without any issues .So you can,

```
$ echo "test multiline
inuput to
my multiline file" > multi_file.dat
```

So add the line feed `(\n)` within the echo command.